# Arguments to this function?

Tags: python

```
def push(self,item):
    "Enqueue the 'item' into the queue"
    self.list.insert(0,item)
```

I am getting a `TypeError` when calling this function like this:

```
horizon.push(start)
```

Python says I need three arguments and only have two. I venture to guess that self is the second of the two I have? But why do I need a third? That doesn't make sense given the definition of `push()`.

I know this is just my inexperience with Python showing. Can someone please educate me about what's going on here?

This is the Pacman search algorithm exercise for a class. I don't want to ask anything that could amount to academic dishonesty so I wanted to minimize the amount of code I post.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pacman.py", line 681, in <module>
    runGames( **args )
  File "pacman.py", line 647, in runGames
    game.run()
  File "/home/user/Documents/search/game.py", line 608, in run
    agent.registerInitialState(self.state.deepCopy())
  File "/home/user/Documents/search/searchAgents.py", line 116, in    registerInitialState
    self.actions  = self.searchFunction(problem) # Find a path
  File "/home/user/Documents/search/search.py", line 105, in uniformCostSearch
    horizon.push(start)
TypeError: push() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

`push()` is a member of class `PriorityQueue`.

Edited this again, previously I mistakenly posted the class `Queue`, not `PriorityQueue`.

```
class PriorityQueue:
    """
      Implements a priority queue data structure. Each inserted item
      has a priority associated with it and the client is usually interested
      in quick retrieval of the lowest-priority item in the queue. This
      data structure allows O(1) access to the lowest-priority item.

      Note that this PriorityQueue does not allow you to change the priority
      of an item.  However, you may insert the same item multiple times with
      different priorities.
    """
    def  __init__(self):
        self.heap = []
        self.count = 0

    def push(self, item, priority):
        # FIXME: restored old behaviour to check against old results better
        # FIXED: restored to stable behaviour
        entry = (priority, self.count, item)
        # entry = (priority, item)
        heapq.heappush(self.heap, entry)
        self.count += 1

    def pop(self):
        (_, _, item) = heapq.heappop(self.heap)
        #  (_, item) = heapq.heappop(self.heap)
        return item

    def isEmpty(self):
        return len(self.heap) == 0
```

Comment: That code wouldn't give that error. Please show the *full* traceback, plus the rest of the class definition (what are `self.list`and `horizon`)?

Comment: Include the full backtrace.  Also, is your push function a method, or is it a stand-alone function?  You may need to show more of your code

Comment: Not related, but you shouldn't implement a queue this... Pushing will scale linearly

Comment: You've probably forgot to initialize horizon. Seems like at this point it's a class and not a instance.

Comment: I have initialized before the calling push() like this:                                            horizon = util.PriorityQueue()

Comment: Ok well it looks like I'm just an idiot. I was looking at the wrong class. Thanks.

Comment: Well your push method takes `(self, item, priority)`, and you call `horizon.push(item)` -> self is the class instance (horizon), item is the item, and ... you aren't giving a priority, so  you get an error.